# Str replace passing variable with two replacements

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I am trying to str replace a variable
I have the variable `$name` which some have spaces and may also have / forward slashes
eg **Villa Spain/Alicante**
I have used this to create the `str_replace()` for the url

```
$name = str_replace(array(' ','/'), array('-','_'), $name);
```

and this works fine eg **Villa-Spain_Alicante** but on the url it leads to I have used this

```
$name = str_replace(array('-','_'), array(' ','/'), $name);
```

to change it back to get the correct `$name` from the databse but it only replaces the `-` not the `_`

It doesn't return any results as it is looking for Villa Spain_Alicante
Please help

Comment: put your url that you paased to this and also what is your expected output also.

Comment: [Its working for me](https://eval.in/372834) It seems you need to post more relevant code

Comment: `$name = 'Villa Spain/Alicante';
$name = str_replace(array(' ','/'), array('-','_'), $name);
$name = str_replace(array('-','_'), array(' ','/'), $name);
echo $name;` results `Villa Spain/Alicante`. And what is wrong?

Comment: Indeed, your approach works for me too. There is of course another way to handle the replacement by using `strtr()` in connection with an associative array containing search patterns and replacement strings: `$x=array(' '=>'-','/'=>'_');
$t1=strtr('Villa Spain/Alicante',$x); // replace forward ...
$t2=strtr($t1,array_flip($x)); // ... and back again`

Comment: @cars10 even no need to use an array. `$name_to_url = strtr($name, ' /', '-_');` and `$name_from_url = strtr($name, '-_', ' /');` will do the job just fine.

Comment: @John Kilbey will you please do a `var_dump($_GET)` and see if something gets mangled up in the URL query string. Are you sure you're not running `urldecode` somewhere down the line, which would transform ' ' into '%20' and obviously cock up the replacement.